# Unable to commit greyed-out files after rename

Tags: git, image, github, git-commit

I have renamed a couple of images in a project to have their names aligned with the names of the files that I receive from API, strangely some of them did commit and went through to remote repo, and some of them didn't. I am unable to commit them no way, I have tried to rename them, remove them, but even so those are still different in color, no matter if renamed or deleted and pasted again, please advise what can I do in this situation.

Those that are more gray (darker) are the ones that are causing problem
[image]

Thanks

Hi, thanks @jingx this is my git status

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   public/assets/images/.DS_Store
        modified:   public/assets/images/categories/korepetycje/chemia.jpg
        deleted:    public/assets/images/categories/korepetycje/matematyka.jpg
        modified:   public/js/RootHomepage.js
        modified:   public/js/app.js
        modified:   resources/js/RootHomepage.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Matematyka is shown as deleted because I have renamed the file to Matematykaaa.jpg, and it still is grey in color the thing is that I need it to be capitalized - Matematyka, and this is the new name of the file, however git status is showing that the file name is matematyka lowercased
[image]

Comment: What does `git status` on command line show?  If this is happening in a specific UI, you need to let us know which UI you are using.

Comment: @jingx I have updated the post, thanks! What specific UI do you have in mind? This is react with bootstrap

Comment: I meant to ask which *git* UI you are using which is showing the files in grey.

Comment: Git lens, although I'm not sure if this is the source of the problem as git status does not pick up the change in file name either

Comment: True. Only other things I can think of is your .gitignore file, as well as what file system are you using (is the FS case sensitive or insensitive?)

Comment: Thanks anyway, I have public folder in gitignore but uncommenting those rules does not change anything, would you know how to remove those files from remote branch?